# How can I have a cache that returns expired results while it updates?

Tags: python, caching

I have a Python function using cachetools to cache its result with a TTL.

The function itself takes a couple of minutes to run. Is there a way to cache the results a first time and whenever the TTL expires, instead of making the next caller wait for the real invocation that takes a long time, just keep returning the stale value while the actual function runs on the background, and only when it finishes update the cached value?

Edit: It's a flask app that when I open a page it triggers a request to a remote api that takes a long time to respond.
While that happens, the page usually errors because of the timeout.
This is not the end of the world because I can start the app and call the function once to have the cache ready, but once it's TTL expires, the next person to request the page gets the error.

Comment: What will you be using to run the function "in the background"?

Comment: I am fairly new to python so I might not be using the correct terms. It's not that I have a way of calling it in the background. It was more of a "is there a way to do this?".

Comment: There most likely is *some* way, but running things "in the background" is quote not-trivial task in Python, the language does not support that very well by default. And whatever solution you choose for doing so might very much affect how to do the cache you are mentioning.

Comment: It sounds like you need a thread that will sleeps until the TTL expires, then fetches the information, puts it in a queue, recalculates the TTL, and goes back to sleep.  The main thread will keep returning the old information unless there is an item in the queue when it returns that instead.